# NullPointerException when trying to read .json file - Youtube Java Api

Tags: java, json, youtube

I am trying to upload a video in youtube with Java, using youtube's API, but I get this error:

```
Throwable: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
    at youtube.Auth.authorize(Auth.java:55)
    at youtube.UploadVideo.<init>(UploadVideo.java:61)
    at lyricspro.Main.main(Main.java:21)
```

Here is the .json file:

```
{
  "installed": {
      "client_id": "id1234",
      "client_secret": "secret123456"
  }
}
```

And here is the class where the error occurs:

```
package youtube;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.StoredCredential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.DataStore;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Shared class used by every sample. Contains methods for authorizing a user and caching credentials.
 */
public class Auth {

    /**
     * Define a global instance of the HTTP transport.
     */
    public static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();

    /**
     * Define a global instance of the JSON factory.
     */
    public static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

    /**
     * This is the directory that will be used under the user's home directory where OAuth tokens will be stored.
     */
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY = ".oauth-credentials";

    /**
     * Authorizes the installed application to access user's protected data.
     *
     * @param scopes              list of scopes needed to run youtube upload.
     * @param credentialDatastore name of the credential datastore to cache OAuth tokens
     */
    public static Credential authorize(List<String> scopes, String credentialDatastore) throws IOException {


        // Load client secrets.
        Reader clientSecretReader = new InputStreamReader(Auth.class.getResourceAsStream("client_secrets.json"));
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, clientSecretReader);

        // Checks that the defaults have been replaced (Default = "Enter X here").
        if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter")
                || clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith("Enter ")) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Enter Client ID and Secret from https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/apiui/credential "
                            + "into src/main/resources/client_secrets.json");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // This creates the credentials datastore at ~/.oauth-credentials/${credentialDatastore}
        FileDataStoreFactory fileDataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/" + CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY));
        DataStore<StoredCredential> datastore = fileDataStoreFactory.getDataStore(credentialDatastore);

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, scopes).setCredentialDataStore(datastore)
                .build();

        // Build the local server and bind it to port 8080
        LocalServerReceiver localReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8080).build();

        // Authorize.
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, localReceiver).authorize("user");
    }
}
```

The error occurs in this line:

```
Reader clientSecretReader = new InputStreamReader(Auth.class.getResourceAsStream("client_secrets.json"));
```

I have tried to place the .json file in all possible locations inside the project folder, but I can't solve this. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: use getClassLoader()
Auth.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("client_secret.json");

Answer (score 1):

Instead Use the following code:

```
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(new File(".\\client_secret.json"));
GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(fis));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the getClassLoader()

```html
Auth.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("client_secret.json");
```